# How much disk space is allocated in Ubuntu for a new user?

Tags: disk-usage

How much disk space is allocated in Ubuntu 12.04 if new user is added? I have 500GB completely allocated for Ubuntu. If a new user is added then how much disk space will be allocated for him?

Comment: By 'allocated' do you mean how much space is available for the user, or how much they initially use? There are answers for both meanings.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no limitations by default. The new user can take all of free space unless you install special [**quota** program](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/saucy/quota). To install it in Ubuntu, you have to write in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install quota
```

There are plenty of tutorials on how to use **quota** in Linux around the Internet, just search "quota ubuntu".
For quick start, you may use [this tutorial](http://mohannetworking.wordpress.com/2012/09/29/how-to-configure-disk-quotas-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: @MaheshK, if this answer is valid for you, mark it as an answer to your question

Comment: Actually i searched in google and different websites but i did not get answer. thats why i asked question here.

Comment: @MaheshK: If my answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Comment: There is a green tick under votes.

Answer (score 8):

When a new user is created some KByte for his personal folder are allocated.

When the users uses his account some more space is used for config files, caches etc. Depending on the programs used and their settings (like browser cache size) this may grow into a few GByte.

Usually the biggest thing are the personal files a user stores in his account.

Answer (score 5):

In a default Ubuntu install everything is installed into one big partition (after setting aside some for swap), so the system and all users will share the one big space.

There are no per-user limits by default except that regular users are not permitted any more space once 95% of the partition is filled.  This leaves the remaining 5% usable only by system processes such as temporary files, logs etc.  On a modern drive of multi-terabyte size this 5% is usually overkill and you can reduce this as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoverLostDiskSpace#Gain_Just_a_Bit_of_Space) although hopefully there is no need.

As mentioned in the other answer you can turn on quotas in Linux which does allow you to configure per-user quotas but I've found this to be quite complicated.  There may be a graphical front-end that I'm not aware of that may make it easier.